# Is there a way to wrap Erlang code to a certain character limit

Tags: erlang

Suppose I have a method

```
timer:apply_after(timeout, module, method, [Hosts])
```

Is there a tool that can help format this into something like:

```
    timer:apply_after(
                      timeout,
                      module,
                      method,
                      [Hosts]
    )
```

I don't think erl_tidy does this.

Answer (score 1):

You could give prettypr a try. I've never used it myself, and might not give the exact output you specified, but it does format the source code according to the available horizontal space.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this through erl_tidy, by passing an option {printer, fun (Tree, Opts) -> erl_prettypr:format(Tree, [{paper, P}, {ribbon, R} | Opts]) end}.

See http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_prettypr.html#format-2 for details about the ribbon and paper options, and http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_tidy.html#file-2 for info about the printer option.